# How to get this regular expression to match </span>

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

This is the sort of HTML string I will be performing matches on:

```
<span class="q1">+12 Spell Power and +10 Hit Rating</span>
```

I want to get `+12 Spell Power and +10 Hit Rating` out of the above HTML. This is the code I wrote:

```
preg_match('/<span class="q1">(.*)<\/span>/', $gem, $match);
```

But due to `<\/span>` it's escaping the `/` in `</span>` so it doesn't stop the match, so I get a lot more data than what I want.

How can I escape the `/` in `</span>` while still having it part of the pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason that your regex is getting more than you want is because * is greedy, matching as much as possible.  Instead, use *?, which will match as little as possible:

```
preg_match('/<span class="q1">(.*?)<\/span>/', $gem, $match);
```

Comment: That works thanks. Reason I don't want to use the DOMDocument class is that it's a very small piece of HTML and this code will only be run once, I'm collecting data to be put into a database. No need to complicate things. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use regex to parse HTML
2. use DOM, particularly the `loadHTML` method and `getElementsByTagName('span')`

-

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
    $spans = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');
    if ( $spans->length > 0 ) {
     // loop on $spans
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use regex to parse HTML.  Use an HTML parser. See [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php).